# Ubuntu install stuck on formatting dialog

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am helping my friend install Linux, as he wants to go into Lua scripting, and Windows is a nightmare. He wants to keep windows and run Ubuntu in a VM (Virtual Box 6.0.0). Everything was fine until the "write changes to disk dialog".

[image: Frozen Installation]

Is there anything that comes to mind that might cause the VM to freeze on this screen? We are using Ubuntu 19.04 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Gparted from the live Ubuntu session, create the filesystems you want, then reinstall Ubuntu as normal.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Just wanted to point out that I was running 6.0.0. Might want to edit your answer!

Comment: uhh...which part? :)

Comment: He wants to keep windows and run Ubuntu in a VM (Virtual Box 6.0.0). Second sentence.